# Removing sources.list.d/artifactory.sources file coming from base image for security purpose

Tags: docker

I am using base private base image in order to build my image for project. This image will be delivered to client for their purpose and installation. But base image exposes private antifactory link under /etc/apt/sources.links.d, which should not be available as part of final delivery.

```
Dockerfile

FROM code.myorg.com/released/debian:23

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends some-library

RUN apt-get clean
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/artifactory.sources
```

upon building image and after security vulnerability testing, they found that private antifactory links are available under

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/artifactory.sources

artifactory.sources
Types: deb deb-src
URIs: https://private.repo.net/artifactory/service/debian 
Suites: bookworm bookworm-updates bookworm-security bookworm-backports
Components: main contrib
Singed-By: /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/detox.gpg
```

I don't want to deliver the image which exposes the private antifactory location.

I tried couple of commands and available solutions over internet but nothing seems to work.

Either artifactory.sources should be empty or deleted.

Comment: Depending if your final package is delivered with root access to customer? This might be tricky to hide it. Not a perfect solution, but you might try to create user and only grant that particular permission for specified directory file.

Comment: Anyone who has a copy of the image can see all of its layers, and can run it as root; anyone who can run any container has unrestricted root access on its host.  Unless you can make this never have existed in the image (say, via a multi-stage build) you may have to accept distributing this internal URL.